# Is that Hergé at the start of The Adventures of Tintin?

Tags: adventures-of-tintin

Out of curiosity, is the street cartoonist/caricature artist who draws our protagonist at the start of *The Adventures of Tintin (2011)* a "cameo" by creator Hergé?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is actually Hergé in the flea market, he has also appeared in various Tintin comic books as a cameo appearance. [Here's a list of his appearances](http://tintin.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Herg%C3%A9_cameo_appearances).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you notice this, while watching the movie or did you read it in a website?

Comment: I thought it was herge while watching the movie, but confirmed it after I did a bit of google-ing. Peter Jackson and Spielberg are Tintin fanatics, so I dont think they would put some one who looks like Herge but is not herge.

Comment: nice observation.

Comment: @karthik -- I am having a hard time parsing your last comment. Hergé died in 1983, so although the *animated character* may indeed *look* like Hergé, it cannot *be* him; he cannot have done the voice, for example, or the mocap.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: yes, you are right, what I meant was, they would created an animation for Herge though he was not available for the mocap. And when I meant _look like_ I was referring to his physical appearances. Should have framed that sentence a bit clearly, my bad.